# In app purchase test with real payment for Apple

Tags: ios, swift, testing, payment

I developed an ios app that provide in app purchase.I tested in app purchase with Sendbox test user succesfully but I want to make a test with real payment  like real credit cart. By the way my app is in testflight. I didnt submit for review apple store. Can I get payment with real credit card even my app is still in testFlight ?

Comment: No, only in production will you be able to use the production App Store, until then you'll be in sandbox. The sandbox mimics exactly how the App Store will work, so I don't see what extra benefit you'd get from having a real credit card being used.

Comment: thnks for your answer , oki then my app works succesfully with sendbox test user I can get payment now When my app submit to app store , I can get payment . Right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there's no problem with that! only Sendbox tests (they have [Environment: Sandbox] showing up when they want to pay) don't pay .